# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with WeakReference

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, weak-references

I am using below code to verify that weakReferences are garbage collected by collector. But I am getting outOfMemoryError after sometime. I added (-Xmx50m) to reduce memory.

```
    List<WeakReference<Object>> weakList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        weakList.add(new WeakReference<Object>(new BigDecimal(10000)));
        System.out.println(weakList.size());
    }
```

Ideally when memory crunch happens GC should run, and it should collect all weakly referred objects. Why I am getting outOfMemoryError ?

Comment: The `WeakReference` objects themselves take space as well.

Comment: So does the `ArrayList`'s underlying array that grows to receive your `WeakReference` objects.

Answer (score 1):

## Why are you getting issues

You are making a massive array of WeakReferences

## What is the issue

Although weak references do not prevent the object they **point** to being Garbage collected, they themselves cannot be garbage collected while a reference still exists.

So although the BigDecimals are being collected, the WeakReferences and the Array are both growing until there is no memory left.